# Chained PHP controls

Tags: php

I'm making a form validation class and it works like this currently.

```
$validator->setVar($_POST['Username'])
          ->standardFilter(array('XSS', 'SQL_INJECTION'))
          ->customRegex()
          ->replace('This', 'With this')
          ->getResult();
```

While it works perfectly when chained like this, I can't archieve the following result.

```
$validator->setVar($_POST['Username'])
          ->isValidEmail()
          ->isValidPhoneNumber()
          ->isSet()
          ->isNull()
          ->getResult()
```

For example, script returns the following values

```
->isValidEmail() (true)
->isValidPhoneNumber() (true)
->isSet() (false)
```

Basically, I'm going to make an array, fill it with true/false depending on the result of each function, and I'll look for a specific value in array (a false). If it exists, the class will return false regardless of the rest of the chains. (or I can just override variables, not important here.)

However, I want $validator to stop chaining once it gets a false from a function. Let's say it received a false from isSet(). It shouldn't execute isNull() and getResult() since we already have a failed check.

How can I archieve this in PHP?

**TL;DR:**

```
var_dump($validator->setVar('Test message')->isInteger()->setTrue());
                                             //false     //true

Output: false, because once isInteger() failed, rest of the chain isn't executed.
```

How can I archieve this in PHP?

Comment: Keep a property (flag) in $validator updated whether or not one of the validation functions returned false, at every request for isSet, isNull check the property first that keeps track of it.

Comment: BTW: it is 'standard' not 'standart' (in `standartFilter`)

Comment: In my local language, it is standart. :p Fixed it though, since function names are meant to be english in this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
class FooBar
{
  private $SomethingWrong = false;

  function Bar()
  {
    if( $this->SomethingWrong )
      throw new Exception('SomeThing is wrong');
    return $this;
  }

  function Foo()
  {
    return $this
  }
}

$foobar = new FooBar();
$foobar->Bar()
       ->Foo();
```

The Foo() part will not be executed, because of the exception in the Bar().

Of course, there are some variations. If you do not want a exception, but a silent non-execute, you could try this:

```
class FooBar
{
  private $SomethingWrong = false;

  function Bar()
  {
    $this->SomethingWrong = true;
    return $this;
  }

  function Foo()
  {
    if( !$this->SomethingWrong )  {
      // do my stuff
    }
    return $this
  }
}
```

Comment: Exceptions are for handling "exceptional" circumstances, not for branching code. This is a poor design suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing like good source code to learn from.  I would suggest exploring the Zend Framework's [Validation classes](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/db_Zend_Validate_Abstract.html).  It provides the same [chaining functionality](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.validator_chains.html) you describe.

...[More source code](http://phpcrossref.com/zendframework/library/Zend/Validate.php.html) check isValid() specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this, in any language, is to throw an exception. You can't return the validator object (which is necessary for chaining) and also return true or false, all while having the chaining work. That said, I am *not* advocating the use of exceptions in this manner. I am in complete agreement with vascowhite's comments below.

Rather than have it stop in the middle of the chain, why not consider the `isSet`, `isNull`, etc. methods as instructions to tell the validator what to check. Then have a `validate` method called at the end of the chain. The `validate` method can perform the validation based on the validator state (as set by the other methods). And that `validate` method can also return a true or a false, or a custom state object, with the result of the validation.

Comment: Exceptions are for handling "exceptional" circumstances, not for branching code. This is a poor design suggestion.

Comment: @vascowhite See my second paragraph--that's the bulk of my suggestion. I am *not* suggesting he use exceptions to fail validation; quite the opposite. My first paragraph is only suggesting that exceptions are the only way he can make his desired chain and still have the execution of that chain interrupted if one of the steps fails.

Comment: I just wanted to make the point really so many people seem to be suggesting using exceptions as a solution to this. Is it possible for you to edit your answer to make it more obvious that exceptions shouldn't be used this way? Your second paragraph is, as you say, a sound suggestion. Sorry for not making that clear in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of return a value, you can throw a custom exception, which abort the code execution.
Add an try-catch block to the code, handle your exception and everything works fine.

EDIT:
What you also can do is a little bit magic and not really to be recommed. But nice to know, this is possible in php, so better use Exceptions

```php
class PassThroughValidator extends ...
{
    private $val;

    public function __construct($result)
    {
        $this->val = $result;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }
}

class EmailValidator extends ...
{

    function isMail()
    {
        if (...) {
            // do something here
            return $this;
        }

        // set Result to false or something similar
        return new PassThroughValidator($this->getResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed a good option to completely prevent any further methods to be executed in the chained list, although it will probably require as many custom exceptions as validation methods, not to forget catching each one of them separately.

Comment: Simple as this: `try { var_dump($validator->setVar('Test message')->assertIsInteger()->setTrue()); } catch ( FailedAssertionException $e ) { var_dump($e); }`

Comment: Could you give me a little example? My mind is about to explode today, 12+ hours of non-stop coding sucks.

Comment: Almost - you can define one General exception for invalid Inputs and all methods who throw an exception inhertis from this exception. So you can catch the super exception.

Comment: Exceptions are for handling "exceptional" circumstances, not for branching code. This is a poor design suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the value returned in each step of the chain is an object, you can not have one of the chained methods return true/false.  it must always return an object instance. So I guess what you would need to do is add some property on the object to indicate that validations should not be done, and if the property is set, just ignore the validation attempt and return the object as is.

So perhaps something like this in simplified form, showing only one such validation:

```
class validator {
    protected $ignore_validations = false;
    protected $value = null;
    protected $is_null;

    public function isNull () {
        if(true === $this->ignore_validations) {
            return $this;
        } else if(is_null($this->value)) {
            $this->is_null = true;
            $this->ignore_validations = true;
            return $this;
        } else {
            $this->is_null = false;
            return $this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this would be a down vote.  Perhaps one fo the supporters for the exception approach made this vote. I personally think it is bad practice to throw exceptions for cases that you know will regularly occur within the execution of the code (like validation conditions will).  This is a very weird request to begin with, and I wouldn't approach this problem in this manner personally, but to suggest that perhaps throwing exceptions is the best solution seems quite odd to me.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I don't see how this achieves the aim of the question. If you ignore the validations, you might as well not run them at all, which is clearly not what is required.

Comment: PS: Agree that this is a marginal case for Exceptions, but they are the only way to "break" a chain like this, because by definition that requires breaking the normal flow of the code.

Comment: @IMSoP THe validations are not being ignored, until such a point that one of the validations fails, at which point the `$ignore_validations` flag is set and the remainder of the chain would do nothing but return the current object as is.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to do. Rather than `$ignore_validations` though, surely the flag should be `$ignore_actions` - as soon as one validation fails, all *write* operations should stop executing, but *read* operations (such as additional validations) won't make any difference.

Comment: On an incidental code-review note, why would you ever run `true ===` on a private variable which you know is always a boolean? i.e. why not just `if ( $this->ignore_validations )`?

Comment: @IMSoP I am just in the habit of being very explicit in my conditionals.  I think it makes the code much more readable to other developers insofar as determining the intent of the conditional.  For example here you can see that I want an exact boolean match of true without having to look throughout the entire class and verifying that only boolean values are ever set for that variable. This also helps enforce the intended boolean nature of the variable throughout the code, as if some other developer were to come along and set that value to `1` or `"true"`, I would want that to break.

Comment: Hm, matter of taste I guess. I find that considerably less readable ("Ooh! There's logic here! Oh, no, it's just a boolean.") and equally error-prone: `if ( 'false' ) #=> true`, but `if ( true === 'true' ) #=> false` which is just as unexpected and would be no more visible a break. I also specifically noted that it was a private (or protected) variable - there is limited code in which the boolean can be clobbered with "untrusted" data.